# In Wolfram Mathematica, who do I query the result of a Counts operation efficiently and conveniently?

Tags: dataset, counting

**Setup**

Say, I'm given a dataset, like the one below:

`titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}]; titanic`

Answering with:

[image: Sample of the Titanic example data]

And I want to count the occurrences of any combination between `{ "1st", "2nd"}` and `{"female", "male"}`, using the `Counts` operator on the dataset, like:

`genderclasscounts  = titanic[All, {"class", "sex"}][Counts]`

[image: Gender Class combination counts]

**Problem statement**

This is *not* a "flat" dataset and I don't have a clue how to query in the usual way, like:

`genderclasscount[Select[ ... ], ...]`

The resulting dataset doesn't provide "column" names to be used as parameters in the `Select` nor can I refer to the number representing the count by a name.

And I've no clue how to express an `Association` as a value in a `Select`!?

Furthermore, try `genderclasscount[Print]`, this demonstrates the values presented to the operation over this dataset are just numbers!

**An unsatisfactory attempt**

Of course, I can "flatten" the `Counts` result, by doing something horrific and inefficient like:

```
temp = Dataset[(row \[Function] 
     AssociationThread[{"class", "sex", "count"} -> row]) /@ (Nest[
      Normal, genderclasscounts, 3] /. 
     Rule[{Rule["class", class_], Rule["sex", sex_]}, 
       count_] -> {class, sex, count})]
```

[image: Flattened Counts over a dataset result]

In this form it is easy to query a count result:

`First@temp[Select[#class == "1st" \[And] #sex == "female" &], "count"]`

**Question**

So, my questions are

1. How can I query the (immediate) result of the `Count` operation in a convenient and efficient fashion, like using a `Select` operation on the resulting dataset? Or, if that is not possible;
2. Is there an efficient and convenient transformation of the `Counts` result dataset possible facilitating such a query?  With "convenient" I mean, for example, that you just provide the dataset and the transformation handles the rest. So, not something like I've shown above in my unsatisfactory "solution" ;-)

Thanks for reading this far and I'm looking forward to anwsers and inspiration.

/@nanitous

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
titanic[KeyValueMap[Append[#, "counts" -> #2] &]@*Counts, {"class", "sex"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is certainly more efficient than my own kludge and it is convenient in its brevity. And to boot, it opens up some new insight how to use datasets.  Again thanks!.  Not in anyway intended to diminish your solution, a little thing is bugging me terse as your solution is, it feels rather alien to me. Is there some way of reasoning here assisting you in coming up with such a solution? Other than sheer brainpower and experience ;-)

Comment: @nanitous, thank you for the accept. Re _reasoning_ behind, squinting at `Normal[titanic[Counts,{"class", "sex"}]` realized something like `KeyValueMap` might work.

Comment: Well, your answer gave me probably the same insight. But way later ;-)